# Write 100'000 rows in xml file with Xdocument take too long time

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I try to add rows nodes inside a xml file which already exists, and add an average of (100'000 rows) inside.
Everything works, but it's really slow.. I don't why. I have to stop my program because it has been 10 minutes and still hasn't finished ^^.

I use the Xdocument class to add the nodes, and XmlTextWriter because i need search the descendant node (Region) with attribute and after add the node inside.

many thanks

**Here is my xmlFile**

```
<World>
  <Matrix>
    <Regions>
      <Region id="0" min="x:0;y:0;z:0" max="x:256;y:16;z:256">
        <Structures type="cube" >
        </Structures>
      </Region>
      <Region id="1" min="x:256;y:0;z:0" max="x:512;y:16;z:256">
        <Structures type="cube" >
        </Structures>
      </Region>
      <Region id="2" min="x:512;y:0;z:0" max="x:768;y:16;z:256">
        <Structures type="cube" >
        </Structures>
      </Region>
      // till Region id="512" ...
```

**And the code i use to insert the new node**

***Update : Use the StringBuilder for improve memory usage*** Like @threeFx advise me

```
// Loop 100'000 times in a recursive method ...

// Search the good node
var reg = arcadia.xDocumentWorld.Descendants("Region").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Attribute("id").Value == region.Index.ToString());
var struc = reg.Element("Structures");
//string posMin = "x:"+ node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.X+";y:"+ node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.Y+"z:"+ node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.Z;
//string posMax = "x:"+ node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Max.X+";y:"+ node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Max.Y+"z:"+ node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Max.Z;

var sbMin = new StringBuilder();
var sbMax = new StringBuilder();

sbMin.Append("x:");
sbMin.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.X);
sbMin.Append("y:");
sbMin.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.Y);
sbMin.Append("z:");
sbMin.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.Z);

sbMax.Append("x:");
sbMax.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Max.X);
sbMax.Append("y:");
sbMax.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Max.Y);
sbMax.Append("z:");
sbMax.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Max.Z);

var cube = new XElement("Cube", new XAttribute("id", node_.ItemGroup),
                                new XAttribute("min", sbMin.ToString()),
                                new XAttribute("max", sbMax.ToString()));

//Add the new cube node
struc.Add(cube);

//Dispose the StringBuilder
sbMin.Clear();
sbMax.Clear();
```

As i see now with a test analys performance , the .Net Linq [List.FirstOrDefault] cost a lot of performance..

```
var reg = arcadia.xDocumentWorld.Descendants("Region").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Attribute("id").Value == region.Index.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: To narrow things down: have you tried profiling (with a smaller dataset) your program to see where the hot spots are?

Comment: i just finish now a basic test of performance and put a picture . I plan to make another test now with CLR Profiler for check the memory GC.

Answer (score 3):

Concatenating strings using `+` is **really** inefficient because for every use of `+` a new instance is created. Your better off if you use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("x:");
sb.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Mix.X);
sb.Append("y:");
sb.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Min.Y);
sb.Append("z:");
sb.Append(node_.CubeNode.BoundingBox.Mix.Z);

string posMin = sb.ToString();

sb.Clear();

// do the same for posMax
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer ^^ You are right , . I change my code now and update my description . But the result is still same, just maybe improve the memory usage with stringbuilder instand string. Build my xml file is still very slow when i want build it . Do you have some idea why ?

Comment: @MehdiBugnard Does the method has to be recursive? Recursive methods in C# are generally slower (there are exceptions) than iterative loops because C# does not support [Tail call optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization).

Comment: Yes this code is inside a recursive methode , but if i run this code without try to write in xml file , this is really fast ( 9-10 secondes) . So that mean , it's slow because i try to write into a xml file in a recursive method ?

Comment: @MehdiBugnard It may be that the most expensive part is the actual the writing and not the recursion.

Comment: mhh i got it, i just finish now to make a test of performance , i see that my call .Linq "List.FirstOrDefault" cost a lot of performance. I put a picture of the results in my description .So maybe the problem can be the Query Linq . but i don't know another way to use

Comment: I would build a seperate Dictionary<string,Node> as I build the XML and use this to find the appropriate Region node rather than searchig the Xml tree via FirstOrDefault(). This will radically improve your performance.

Comment: Thank you PhilipH !! This is almost the good answer, before i always use FirstOfDefault , even on Xelement i already search before ! Now I create an array => XElement[] regStruc = new XElement[512]; And save inside it , so i can use again the Xelement i already search before. Do you can add this as an answer please ?